# How to choose based on specific multiples of indexes from array

Tags: ruby

This is probably very basic question.

Suppose I have an array with 19 items `[0,1,2,3,4..19]`. How could I selecting only the ones with the index count that are multiples of a given number i.e. 2?

**Updated:** Supposed this code is intended to use for columns. How to manage to get indexes that would be of first column given that all are multiple of one?

Comment: Do you mean if the array index is a multiple of 2 or the actual value at that index is a multiple of 2?

Comment: Please give an actual example of what you have and what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select elements which are multiples of a given number (works if your elements equal the index):

```
ary.select { |element| element % 2 == 0 }
```

In this special case, you can also use symbol to proc:

```
ary.select &:even?
```

If your elements are different from the indices, group in pairs of 2 and use the first element:

```
ary.each_slice(2).map { |slice| slice[0] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) (`Array` includes `Enumerable`).  You can do this:

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1.9.3p392 :002 > a.select {|n| n % 2 == 0}
 => [2, 4, 6]
```

`select` will filter the array, picking out anything for which the block returns true.  In this case, using the mod (`%`) operator to find elements divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to take only the even indices.  Try using [each_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index).

```
arr = (0..19).to_a
arr.each_index { |x| puts arr[x] if x % 2 == 0 }
```

This prints:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

If you want the even elements of the array you could use `find_all` too.

```
arr.find_all { |e| e.even? }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..19).to_a.select{|e| e.%(2).zero?}
```

This is slightly faster than using `== 0`.